# Changing active tab without Jquery

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, tabs, navbar

I looked for similar posts but they all seem to resort to Jquery, which by now is considered outdated in most cases.

My question is:
How can I change the class of active (currently on my "Projects" labeled  tag, to the siblings when clicking it?

I'm really trying to achieve results with only Vanilla Javascript and hopefully a .forEach method, to make it more functional.

Sorry for not providing any JS at this moment, it seems I'm really struggling with the basics .

```
<nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link active">PROJECTS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">CREATION PROCESS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">BEFORE AND AFTER</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT THE STUDIO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

EDIT:
Thanks to the first reply, I managed to figure out a clean and modern way to refactor it to my taste:

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

tabs.forEach(tab => tab.addEventListener('click', toggleActiveTab));

function toggleActiveTab(e) {
tabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.classList.remove('active');
});
e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', printDetails);
}

function printDetails(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].classList.contains("active")) {
      items[i].classList.toggle("active")
    }
  }
  this.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<nav id="sidebar">
  <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link active">PROJECTS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">CREATION PROCESS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">BEFORE AND AFTER</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT THE STUDIO</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Add an event listener to each `nav-link` if you can't add onClick event to HTML code.

Then in the click method check for active class in each `nav-link` element, if active class is present then toggle it.

Then add active class to the clicked tab.